# How do I plot tweets as points on an image in processing?

Tags: api, twitter, processing

I've been trying to plot tweets with certain hashtags on a picture in processing but haven't been able to find any good resources or assistance.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. Stack Overflow is designed more for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. That being said, I'll try to answer in a general sense:

You need to break your problem down into smaller steps.

**Step 1:** You can draw your image using the [`image()`](https://processing.org/reference/image_.html) function. Get a sketch working that does **just this** without worrying about the tweets just yet.

**Step 2:** You can use a library like [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) to retrieve tweets with certain hashtags. Put together a completely separate sketch that just retrieves tweets and prints them out to the console. Don't worry about displaying them.

**Step 3:** You can use the [`text()`](https://processing.org/reference/text_.html) function to display text on your screen. Again, get a simple application working first before you try combining it with the other steps.

When you have each of those steps working by themselves, then you can start thinking about combining them into one sketch. Focus on one small step at a time, and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it shot!

Comment: I have a program that is running with the Twitter4j and is pulling tweets with the hashtags I specified, and I have a query for tweets within a certain area.  Is there any one who can look at a copy of my code for errors?

Comment: @AnnalieseGottschalk That really isn't how Stack Overflow works. Please post a specific question (I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead. Why does this line do this instead of that?) along with a [mcve], and we'll go from there.